# How to find XPath for the banner text?

Tags: html, xpath

[image: <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l09ro.png" />]

The text is Investors/ Lenders get access to creditworthy borrowers to lend funds as per their risk appetite and gain attractive stable returns or monthly income to create wealth.
How to find xpath for mentioned text?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Firstly let us know what have you tried to achieve.

Comment: You need to elaborate the question with more details to get the right answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible with XPath-2.0 or above, because you need the `fn:string-join` function to merge the `text()` values in one XPath expression:

```
string-join(normalize-space(//p[@class='banner-text']))
```

I haven't tested this expression, because you chose to include code as image and not as text. Probably the `== $0` text is included in the result. You can fix this with the `fn:substring-after` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath:

```
//p[@class='banner-text']
```

Here is the css:

```
p.banner-text
```

Tested in Chrome Console with below xpath and css.

**xpath:**

```
document.evaluate("//p[@class='banner-text']", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotItem(0).innerText
```

**CSS:**

```
document.querySelector(".banner-text").innerText
```

**Using JQuery:**

```
$x("//p[@class='banner-text']")[0].innerText
```

**Result for all the three above:**

```
Investors/ Lendors "get access to creditworty" borrowers "to lend funds per their risk appetite and gain attractive stable returns or monthly income to create wealth."
```